# how to show the last message of the conversation using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have User section field, wherein i have users, so now i have to display the last message below the user.How do i make the message to display there.

HTML:

```
<mat-tab label="Active">
          <mat-icon for="search">search</mat-icon>
          <input type="search" name="search" class="search" placeholder="Company">
          <ul>
            <li *ngFor="let message of activeMessages" (click)="showMessage(message)" [class.activeShow]="message.id == message_id">
              <span>{{message.updated_at  | date:'dd.MM.yyyy'}}</span>
              <img style="width: 40px;" [src]="message.from_user_image || '../assets/images/msg.png'"/>
              <p style="padding-top: 16px;display: inline;">{{message.from_user_name}}</p>
              <p style="padding-top: 10px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;"><b>{{message.text}}</b></p>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </mat-tab>
```

This is dummy i had added, in this i need the last message conversation to display there.

```
<p style="padding-top: 10px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;"><b>{{message.text}}</b></p>
```

Last message conversation is here.

```
loadMessages() {
    this.service
          .getMessages()
          .subscribe(
            data => {
              this.messagesdata = data;
              this.activeMessages = data.filter(msg => msg.active == true && msg.from_user_name !== 'Anonymus' && msg.messages.length > 0)
              this.closedMessages = data.filter(msg => msg.active == false && msg.from_user_name !== 'Anonymus' && msg.messages.length > 0);
              if (this.activeMessages.length > 0) {
                if(!this.message_show) {
                  var test = this.message_show = this.activeMessages[0];
                  this.message = true;
                  this.message_id = this.activeMessages[0].id;
                  this.message_show.messages.map(function(msg) {
                    if(msg.from_user_id == test.from_user_id) {
                      msg.from_user_image = test.from_user_image;
                    } else {
                      msg.from_user_image = test.to_user_image;
                    }
                    if(msg.to_user_id == test.to_user_id) {
                      msg.to_user_image = test.to_user_image;
                    } else {
                      msg.to_user_image = test.to_user_image;
                    }
                  })
                }
              }             
            },error => {});
  }
```

In this i get messages field inside an array

```
var test = this.message_show = this.activeMessages[0];
```

so in activeMessages[0].messages i get list of messages, i want the latest message to display in html.

Consoled:
[image]

Comment: Can you share us what  this.activeMessages[0] object contains

Comment: ya i had updated

Comment: then you can print last message like below.. this.activeMessages[0].messages[this.activeMessages[0].messages.length-1]

Comment: how do i print that in html?

Comment: <p style="padding-top: 10px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;"><b>{{message.text}}</b></p>

Comment: <p style="padding-top: 10px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;"><b>{{activeMessages[0].messages[activeMessages[0].messages.length-1]}}</b></p>

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'messages' of undefined

Comment: Initially it will not be there right so you have to put ngIf...
<p style="padding-top: 10px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;" *ngIf="activeMessages[0] && activeMessages[0].messages"><b>{{activeMessages[0].messages[activeMessages[0].messages.length-1]}}</b></p>

Comment: here i have <li *ngFor="let message of activeMessages" (click)="showMessage(message)" [class.activeShow]="message.id == message_id">

Comment: i am getting [object object]

Comment: <p style="padding-top: 10px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;"><b>{{message.messages[message.messages.length -1]}}</b></p>

Comment: again same getting [object object], because inside messages i have text field i need that text to display

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this below line

```
   <p style="padding-top: 10px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;"><b>{{message.text}}</b></p>
```

with

```
 <p style="padding-top: 10px;white-space: nowrap;overflow: hidden;text- 
     overflow: ellipsis;"><b>{{message.messages[message.messages.length -1].text}}</b></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last element of your activeMessages inside your component like this:

```
let lastMessage:any = this.activeMessages[0][this.activeMessages[0].length-1];
```

and then access the `lastMesage` variable inside your html. If you want the lastMessage text you should access like this inside your html.

```
<p> {{lastMessage.text}} </p>
```

Comment: i need the text of last message

Comment: you can take this like this lastMessage.text